# Styles are being shown only in index.php

Tags: css, cakephp, sass, directory

I am trying to make my CakePHP project use the same CSS stylesheet for all pages. Currently, it is being displayed only on one page (the index page). It seems like for some reason it is not finding the correct directory.

How can this be fixed, please?

[This is how it is shown in the index page when I inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXkT.png)

[This is how it is shown in other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xosw.png)

[Style sheet in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt8Mw.png)

[Reference to stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdSv.png)

Comment: _"It seems like for some reason it is not finding the correct directory."_ - what are the URLs/paths of the main document you are trying to embed it in, in each case? You used a relative URL to refer to your stylesheet, so what that will actually point to, of course depends on the "folder depth" of the URL of the embedding document. Use root-relative URLs starting with a slash to easily avoid such issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment CBroe, I don't know if this maybe helps you, I referenced the css file with this (./css/style.css) now and when I am in the index page it references it correctly with ( localhost/dashboard/LaLioggia/css/style.css ) but when I go into my cart for example the reference returns to ( localhost/dashboard/LaLioggia/cart/mycart/css/style.css) for some reason..

Comment: That is simply how relative URLs _work_ - the relative path gets completed to a full one using the path of the embedding document as basis. As I said, the easiest way to avoid any such problems, is to embed your assets referring to the web root, by using a path with a leading slash.